# Obter dados table HTML pelo JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

Busco os dados no banco e monto um table no meu JSP. As informações são de vários voos de uma companhia área.

O objetivo é escolher uma passagem aérea entre todas as carregadas.

Pretendo colocar um *link* "comprar" em cada linha e, ao clicar, fazer uma requisição com os dados daquela linha, porém, não faço ideia de como percorrer o `Table` pegando as informações de apenas uma linha para montar a requisição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
// loop foreach
<tr>
<td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td><a onclick="comprar(passa o id aqui)">COMPRAR</a></td>
</tr>  
// loop foreach
</table>
```

No seu loop já separa uma TD para criar botão de COMPRAR, cria uma function que eu chamei de comprar recebendo teu ID, e ai faz todo tratamento via JS ou JQuery.

Mas fácil ainda pode ser assim, substituindo a linha abaixo.
    `<td><a href='localhost/comprar/ID_AQUI>COMPRAR</a></td>`

E na sua controller vc cria um request utilizando GET pegando esse ID, daí faz sua lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Lucas,

1. Quando for carregar as passagens aéreas, carrega os IDs também,
   pois vai precisar deles;
2. No link "comprar", chama um método passando como parâmetro o ID
   da passagem;
3. No método, faz um SELECT no banco, buscando os dados daquela passagem,
   no SELECT é claro que na condição (WHERE) você vai colocar o ID
   da passagem.